# May I ask how to understand the following bash script?

Tags: bash, sed

May I ask what the following bash script is trying to do?

```
args=$(echo $@ |sed "s/^ *//;s/ *$//;s/ \{1,\}/ /g;s/-\{1,\} /-/g;s/ -/\t-/g")
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script *trims* the arguments passed to the script via commandline. (The array of all arguments can be addressed using `$@` in the shell)

Trimming means, it removes redundant whitespace in the middle of strings and removes whitespace completely at the start and end of each arguments. Your code will further replace a space in front of a hyphen by a `TAB`.

Transformations, made by the command, in detail:

```
s/^ *//          --> remove 0 or more spaces at the start of the string
s/ *$//          --> remove 0 or more spaces at the end of the string
/ \{1,\}/ /g     --> "melts" multiple spaces into one
s/-\{1,\} /-/g   --> Removes one or more white space after the hypen `-`
s/ -/\t-/g       --> Removes a space in front of a hypen by a TAB
```

Answer (score 2):

Let us break it down:

1. `s/^ *//;`
2. `s/ *$//;`
3. `s/ \{1,\}/ /g;`
4. `s/-\{1,\} /-/g;`
5. `s/ -/\t-/g`

   **1.** Removes spaces at the beginning of line

   **2.** Removes spaces at the end of line

   **3.** Replaces spaces by a single space

   **4.** Replaces dashes by asingle dash

   **5.** Replaces space and dash by tab and dash

Answer (score 1):

Let's split it in small pieces, so it's easier to understand:

1. Remove any spaces at the start of a line

   ```
   s/^ *//;
   ```
2. Remove any spaces at the end of a line

   ```
   s/ *$//;
   ```
3. Replace two or more spaces with a single space

   ```
   s/ \{1,\}/ /g;
   ```
4. Replace two or more dashes followed by a space `-` by a single dash

   ```
   s/-\{1,\} /-/g;
   ```
5. Replace a space and a dash `-` with a tab and a dash `\t-`

   ```
   s/ -/\t-/g
   ```

Comment: @AvinashRaj Well, `{1,}` means "one or more space", but since this gets replaced by a single space, it *effectivly* means "Replace two or more spaces with a single space".

Answer (score 1):

The `sed` cleans up the spaces and changes this:

```
sdfgsdfg
  afadsfads fadsf
adsfadf   adfadfads
adfadfa - adsfdsf
dfadsf - dsfds
dfsd   -   sdfsd
```

To this:

```
sed "s/^ *//;s/ *$//;s/ \{1,\}/ /g;s/-\{1,\} /-/g;s/ -/\t-/g" file
sdfgsdfg
afadsfads fadsf
adsfadf adfadfads
adfadfa -adsfdsf
dfadsf  -dsfds
dfsd    -sdfsd
```

You can do it more simple by using `awk`

```
awk '{$1=$1;sub(/ - /,"\t-")}1' file
sdfgsdfg
afadsfads fadsf
adsfadf adfadfads
adfadfa -adsfdsf
dfadsf  -dsfds
dfsd    -sdfsd
```

Or in your case:

```
args=$(echo $@ | awk '{$1=$1;sub(/ - /,"\t-")}1')
```